# Etiqueta audio no suena en ios , iphone

Tags: html5, ios

Tengo un blog sobre una radio online, uso un reproductor con etiqueta audio, resulta que funciona correctamente en windows, en android y en los navegadores Opera, Chrome y mozilla. Lo raro es que hasta hace una semana funcionaba bien también en iOS Apple notebook y en IPhone. Luego dejó de funcionar en iOS.
En el código no utilizo autoplay.

```html
 <audio id='player' preload='true' src='https://radios.tecnosoul.com.ar/djsclubradio'> 
  
   
      
</audio>
```

```html
También tengo esto :

<a><img id='i5' onclick='document.getElementById(&apos;player&apos;).play();changeImage()' src='https://i.ibb.co/Csmqgvd/botongif2.gif' style='float:left;clear:none; z-index:10005;margin-left: 30px;align:middle;' title='ESCUCHAR RADIO'/></a>
```

Comment: Parece que es algo generalizado, te dejo un enlace de en.SO donde comentan algunas soluciones:

[html5 <audio> not playing on IOS Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288130/html5-audio-not-playing-on-ios-safari)

Comment: Gracias por la repuesta, el tema es que tampoco funciona en otros navegadores del iOS pero si en Windows.

Comment: No sé si tiene algo que ver con los certs de la llamada caída cibernética de los otros días. Quiero ofrecer recompensa por la respuesta y solución adecuada.

Comment: Todos los navegadores de iOS son realmente el mismo: la AppStore obliga a que cualquier aplicación que quiera mostrar HTML use el motor WebKit del sistema, hasta Firefox está usando WebKit en lugar de Gecko

Comment: La sección de respuestas es para dar posibles soluciones a la pregunto. Por otro lado existe la sección de comentarios donde puedes aportar mas información sobre la pregunta. Por favor abstente de publicar comentarios como respuestas.

Comment: En mi caso como podría solucionarlo, soy principiante en esto, gracias.

Comment: No me sale la opción para dar recompensa por la repuesta.

Comment: eso posiblemente se deba a que te faltan puntos pare desbloquear esa opción

Comment: lo raro es que con la pregunta anterior si pude y me dieron el premio de Benefactor.

Comment: Desconozco los detalles, a mi solo me tocó moderar tu respuesta. Puede que sea porque en este momento no cuentas con puntos suficientes para ofrecer una recompensa o deba de pasar un tiempo antes de poder ofrecer otra recompensa.

Comment: Utiliza el enlace editar en tu pregunta para añadir información adicional. El botón Publicar respuesta se debe usar solamente para respuestas completas a la pregunta. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/299210)